# Android Gallery fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

How do I implement a fullscreen gallery? i.e. image stretches to fill all the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make it fullscreen:

```
        <activity android:name="YourActivity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

To make the images fill the screen you should do it on your adapter, creating a View with MATCH_PARENT x MATCH_PARENT and in your ImageView you created on getView you should make it fill all the space:

```
yourImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: Would it act like regular gallery widget? I mean image scrolling.

Comment: Yes it will, your adapter should be responsible only to give the data to the Gallery, in case the images. The Gallery will be responsible to scroll the images.

Comment: And how do I create View with MATCH_PARENT x MATCH_PARENT?

Comment: yourImageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Answer (score 2):

Use this in Activity Manifest.xml

Give property like this

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```