# Need to display a link at bottom of image gallery.

Tags: android, galleryview

I am using gallery view to display images in a gallery view in full screen. I have used the suggestion given below:
[Android Gallery fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312909/android-gallery-fullscreen)

The gallery view is fine. 
But I want to divide the screen in 4:1 ratio vertically and display the image in the above partition only. In the lower partition, I want to display a text with link. Now the link should open the target in default browser.

How can i divide the screen?
And is it better to have text or button for the link?

Comment: Why don't you use LinearLayout in vertical orientation with Gallery object which layout_weight=4, layout_height=0 and TextView object, which layout_weight=1 and layout_height=0?

Comment: In such a case how should I define objects like R.layout.main? and R.id.gallery? I didnt understand the mapping between .java code and xml file properly. Could you please help me by refering to one such docs?

Comment: defining value of layout_height=0 poses an error!

Comment: of course, because you need to give the system what kind of measure units you want to use (dp, sp, px)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to create an xml with LinearLayout like teoREtik said. To access it's elements in that xml, you will need the following:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
galleryLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_name, parent, false);
Gallery gallery = (Gallery) galleryLayout.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
```