# What's the best way on Android to create a photo gallery (fullscreen)

Tags: android, imageview, photo-gallery

I wonder what's the best way to create a photo gallery for my app. I get the pictures from an RSS feed and I want to display each of them in fullscreen. What should I use ? I tried with an ImageView but the images are resized in a bad way (they don't keep the original dimensions)

I used this answer to implement my gallery : [Android Gallery fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312909/android-gallery-fullscreen)

Thank's

EDIT :

Here's the XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/galleryPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the code I use in my adapter to load the images :

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    ImageDownloader.getInstance().download(gallery.get(position), ImageFormat.CONTENT_316, imageView);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(imageView, 0);

        return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Someone else left a comment suggesting it, which has since been deleted apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I used above was almost right, I just changed ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY to ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/galleryPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the code I use in my adapter to load the images :

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    imageView.setScaleType(**ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP**);
    ImageDownloader.getInstance().download(gallery.get(position), ImageFormat.CONTENT_316, imageView);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(imageView, 0);

        return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with ImageViews inside of it.

You are able to specify to the ImageView how you'd like the images to be (or not to be) streched with the `android:scaleType` attribute in your xml. If you share some of the code that you were using with ImageViews and maybe give a little bit more info about how you wan them to appear I can try to help you get it set up properly.

Also I suggest you take a look at [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) for best practices to use when dealing with images so as to keep the performance of your app top notch.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I posted my code. With this code the images lose their proportions*

Answer (score 1):

Use an `Adapter` & `ListView` to display images slide.

Now in the adapter item's layout use `ImageView` with `fill_parent` for both width & hight as like following code:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

you may suggest the user to use the phone in landscape mode for better performance. so keep additional layout in *layout-land* folder

Answer (score 0):

one way would be

- get the image url's from the rss feed
- show them as thumbnails in a custom gallery (can setup via horizontal linearlayout with a imageview in it, inside a scrollview)
- use lazyloading of images to show these thumbnails
- override onClickListener to get the click events
- and in this onClick load the current image URL in a webview.
- webview has good features of zoom, move along picture etc..